# How to Detect 'Batch' mode from within a Batch File under Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running a batch (.bat) file via the Windows (Task) Scheduler, a third party cron (nncronLite) and via a "START" command.  I'm trying to work out a way that I can detect the .bat file has been run via one of the above means compared to me running the batch file from a console (cmd.exe) window.

I can try checking an environment variable.. but which one (here I'm trying HOMEDRIVE)?

```
setlocal
set BATCH_MODE=1
if defined HOMEDRIVE set BATCH_MODE=

rem [...]

if defined BATCH_MODE echo IN BATCH MODE
```

Any other suggested mechanims (other than supplying a command line argument to the batch file = kludge, IMO)?

This is for use with Windows XP, Win7, Win8, Win10 (and beyond, I guess)

Thanks.

Comment: Look for _the value_ of `%CMDCMDLINE%` variable...

Comment: @Aacini: That variable shows the actual command line used to invoke the .bat file when in 'batch' mode and just the name (no .bat) of the batch file when run in a console (cmd.exe) window.  So, maybe I can do something with comparing COMSPEC with CMDLINE or CMDCMDLINE.

BTW, where did you find out about the existence of CMDCMDLINE?  It's not shown by a 'SET' command, nor is it included in the System Environment Variables...?

Comment: Type `set` to list all variables, including `CMDCMDLINE`. Type `set /?` to find the help for the `set` command, which includes the predefined environment variables.

Comment: @aschipfl: `set` command does _not_ list the dynamic variables...

Comment: @Aacini, then it's probably `cmd /?`...

Comment: @aschipfl: what I mean is that `set /?` _describes_ all the dynamic variables, and `set` command list the variables defined in the environment. Because its nature, the _dynamic_ variables are _not_ defined in the environment, so `set` command does _not_ list anyone of they, like CMDCMDLINE, ERRORLEVEL, TIME, RANDOM, etc.

Comment: Ah yes, @Aacini, seems I misunderstood you. You are perfectly right, `CMDCMDLINE` is also a dynamic variable of course; sorry for confusion!